# NSURL bookmark query

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsurl

What part of `NSURL` has the bookmark query?

e.g.

```
mypage.htm#part1
```

How can I get the value `#part1`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [fragment](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000301-BAJBEIHD).